# What does the mutation rate actually refer to in a genetic algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, genetic-algorithm, mutation

I have implemented the first, pre-alpha version of my little genetic algorithm framework and it is working very well thus far. Now, I am in the process of writing documentation and finishing up some details. I just wanted to clarify something.

The term "mutation rate". Does it mean:

- The likelyhood of a given chromosome being mutated at all?
- The likelyhood of a given gene in a chromosome being modified?
- Or the likelyhood of a single allele in a gene being modified?

Depending on which of the above is the correct answer (or something entirely different for that matter), please also clarify whether I need to scale the mutation rate by some other value (the number of genes in a chromosome, for instance).

Comment: If I was you, I would post this in http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ or http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: There isn't really a generally agreed upon meaning of "mutation rate." I've seen it used to mean all of the things you mentioned, and more. Ultimately, it comes down to what makes the most sense for your specific application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you implement a single allele, but I would say mutation rate is the chance of a single binary mutating (e.g you have DNA 0000, and a 25% chance of every binary digit, the zeros in this case, to "mutate" to a 1).

In the projects I have done myself I have not scaled the mutation rate.

Edited.

Comment: I have my chromosome bit string divided into genes, so would you apply the mutation rate to each gene or to the entire chromosome string? In both cases, wouldn't you want to scale the mutation rate by either the length of a gene or the length of a chromosome respectively? One approach I can think of is to make the mutation rate the probability that a given gene in a chromosome is modified, and if the random value falls within that bracket, flip the alleles/bits in the gene. Does that sound reasonable, or are there better ways of doing it?

Comment: To me it sounds a little strange that you would apply the mutation rate to a whole gene. If you take the example with your gene being 0000; applying your mutation to that gene would (with 25% mutation rate) 75% 0000 and 25% 1111. With my definition the resulting gene could have all possible combinations of 0's and 1's. So in some way I would say you have to iterate over all alleles, and not think of them as strictly belonging to a gene.

Comment: Ah, now that makes more sense. Thank you! And to be clear, I store each allele as a binary bit. So I will generate a new random number for each bit, and if the random number falls below the mutation rate, I flip the bit. Is that reasonable?

Answer (score 1):

Though there is no universally accepted definition of the term *mutation rate*, in most scholastic contexts it refers to `β`, the probability of mutation of a single bit in binary-encoded GA schemes for each individual.

The mutation rate really comes into play only when dealing with solution spaces with encompass multiple local optima and serve as a corrective measure to ensure global optimality. It should however be confined to a low value range as the larger the mutation rate, the more becomes the convergence time.

A detailed discussion about the same may be found [here](http://www.researchgate.net/post/Why_is_the_mutation_rate_in_genetic_algorithms_very_small).